# Print whole HashMap by jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to print whole map by jasperreport

Example:

```
Column1 Column2

key1        val1

key2        val2

key2        val2
```

What is data source should be choosen?

What should containts report source?

PS: I don't want to get values directly like $P{key11}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
//your map values....
Set<Entry<String,Object>> set = map.entrySet();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource bds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(set);
```

in the jasper report your fields will be

```
<field name="key" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value" class="java.lang.Object"/>
```

Note: How I'm using the `Map.Entry` bean `getKey()` and `getValue()` to created my datasource

The values will not be sorted if you like to sort them just implement a `Comparator` and use `Collections`.

```
    List<Entry<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Object>>();
    list.addAll(set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Object> o1, Entry<String, Object> o2) {
            // TODO Implement you sorting
            return 0;
        }
    });
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource bdsSorted = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
```