# How to setup my Hashmap <key, list> as a datasource for jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have requirement to display HashMap object as jasper datasource

```
Map<String, List<obj>> salesMap= new HashMap<>();    
salesMap.put("10/02/2021", List<Obj>);
salesMap.put("11/02/2021", List<Obj>);
salesMap.put("12/02/2021", List<Obj>);
```

and my datasource

```
private JRMapCollectionDataSource fuelSalesDataSource;

public Map<String, Object> getDataSources() {
    Map<String, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
    dataSources.put("fuelSalesDataSource", fuelSalesDataSource);
    return dataSources;
}
```

and my jasper print

```
    JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(
            new Object[] { fuelSalesReportInputMO.getDataSources() });

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fuel_sales_report);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, fuelSalesReportInputMO.getParameters(),
            dataSource);

    reportData = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
```

I have to display the my HashMap in jasper, how to get hash map key and it list of objects in one single row?

```
       key column          value column          value column     
       10/02/2021         list[0].getType       list[1].getType
       11/02/2021         list[0].getType       list[1].getType.
```

I have field in jrmxl

```
<field name="fuelSalesDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource"/>
```

How to read map in jrxml by key and its values as list?

Comment: are the value columns dynamic, hence are there only two or can there be any number?

Comment: Use a horizontal `List` passing the field value as the datasource.

Comment: @PetterFriberg the value columns are static.. column number is three.. one for key and  other two for list. list contains only two elements..

Comment: @pappu_kutty This is my suggestion. Create a class (that reppresents the row) with fields, key, value1, value2. Do all the logic in java to fill the rows, hence you end up with a List of these objects, pass it to jasper as a JRBeanCollectionDatasource and reference directly your fields

Comment: your code is wrong for some of the reasons in the answer by kendavidson, if you really like to know anyway how to use a JRMapCollectionDataSource I could answer, but it is not the correct datasource for your case, it's just overcomplicating a simple thing.

Comment: @PetterFriberg , it is complicated logic.. i can simply have two list.. but elements inside those list are related to each other, how can i relate, only through map i can releate.. i have key value in each list.. but i have to do logic in jasper while priting .. again this is more complicated..

Comment: @pappu and you can't do this complicate logic in java? Becuse from developer stand point it would be better to keep it in Java and send clean datasource to jasper

Comment: @PetterFriberg, i saw your answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362483/print-whole-hashmap-by-jasperreport , will it work in this scenario ?...

Comment: @pappu_kutty you can do this in tons of different ways, but according to me the correct way is only one, you should not bring complex logic into jasper report when there is no need (hence you can solve the problem cleanly in java), I will post an answer so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i have fixed the issue, and as pointed out by @Petter, i changed my datasource to JRBeanCollectionDataSource from JRMapCollection...

code below

```
public JRBeanCollectionDataSource  getFuelSalesReportDataSource() {
    Map<String, List<DailyFuelSalesMO>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(dailyFuelSalesMap);
    Set<Entry<String,List<DailyFuelSalesMO>>> set = sortedMap.entrySet();
    fuelSalesReportDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(set);
    return fuelSalesReportDataSource;
}
```

and jrxml, i have fields as below..

```
    <field name="key" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="value[0].fuelObj.type" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <field name="value[0].fuelObj.priceObj.price" class="java.lang.Double"/>         
    <field name="value[1].fuelObj.type" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <field name="value[1].fuelObj.priceObj.price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
```

so i could able to populate in single row, with key, and its list values, in this i have two list object per key, so i could able to get those objects by value[i] for each key object in the hashmap...

Answer (score 1):

Jasper report is a reporting tool, it would be possibile to use a `JRMapCollectionDataSource` or any other type and then reference the list, the position of an object in a list in a specific text field, but since you are creating your data in java in my opinion you should keep all this logic in java. It has no sense to try to solve your problem in jasper report when you can solve it in a clean way within your java application.

**This is what I would have done:**

Create a class the represent the output in report

```
@Data // lombok that generates getter/setter (if you don't have it do them in code)
public class ReportData {   
    private String date;
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
}
```

Then in java setup the the data

```
final List<ReportData> data = new ArrayList<>();

//Maybe add some sorting (HashMap is unsorted)?
salesMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
    
    ReportData rp = new ReportData();
    rp.setDate(e.getKey());
    //Here you should check size of list etc 
    rp.setValue1(e.getValue().get(0));
    rp.setValue2(e.getValue().get(1));
    data.add(rp)
});

//Then now pass it to report
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, fuelSalesReportInputMO.getParameters(),
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
```

Like this now in jasper report you just field names as in `ReportData` eg

```
<field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: @AlexK maybe but I'm not sure of what, because the real problem here is that according to me OP is using wrong approach, hence the problem is that they are trying do something in jasper report that should be done in java... now what is the dupe for that? I was hoping to explain in comments, but it got so far that it was easier to answer to show the correct approach. I had an idea to show how to use the JRMapCollectionDataSource which maybe would have been more useful for SO.. but it's just not the right solution for their problem.

Comment: @Alex we would need something general about converting a Map<?, List<?>> to a List of objects + the dupe JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

Comment: @AlexK sure.. and basic jasper-report... but is not everything on SO this :D

Comment: I'm all for the 1:1 of Jasper:Bean when building reports.  But I fully understand that sometimes (when 10s of reports are required) replacing the Beans with Maps speeds up the process (I get it, but being realistic).

Answer (score -1):

After re-reading this, I think you're using the wrong data types for your collections.  You're using:

`JRMapCollectionDataSource` which expects a `Collection<Map>` which is not what you have.  You have a single Map which you'd like to iterate though.

which you're wrapping in

`JRMapArrayDataSource` which expects an `Array<Map>` which you're just passing in an Array[1] with your single map data collection.

Assuming you want all your `dates = row` you need to pass in multiple maps.  Something that might look like this:

```
data: [
   { date: "10/02/2021", data: List<Obj>) },
   { date: "11/02/2021", data: List<Obj>) },
   { date: "12/02/2021", data: List<Obj>) },
]
```

Now you can pass in your `JRMapCollectionDataSource` directly without wrapping it.  Now you can setup your fields as:

- THIS = java.util.Map (if you want direct access)
- date = java.util.Date
- data = java.util.List

which will allow you to setup the report:

[TextField: $F{date}]
[List: new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{data}), horizontal]

which should give you close to the output you're looking for.

If this is way off the mark, sorry.